# define a schema with JSON-Schema and use Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, schema, asp.net-web-api, jsonschema

Hullo,
I  have a crux to bear with Mongoose.
Is there a way of using JSON-Shema with Mongoose Schemas? 
Say I want to define my API data schema using a standard like JSON-Schema, because it's nice.
It seems like I need to define it again when I want to use Mongoose / MongoDB!
That's quite some ugly duplication I like to avoid. Ideally, changing the JSON-Schema definition would also change the MongoDB schema. 
A similar problem would appear if I would use JOI.JS validation library.
Has anyone found a solution to that?
Or is there an alternative approach?

thanks

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to take your json-schema and automatically convert it to a mongoose schema using javascript. at the end of the day, they're just objects once you parse it.

Comment: while that's fair enough, I was wondering if someone did something like that in the past and made that effort available to everyone, as it appears like a pretty obvious problem for me. I researched tools and couldn't find one so far.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-converter

Comment: I updated json-schema-converter to https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-mongoose since it didn't appear that json-schema-converter was being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-mongoose There are others out there too. I created `json-schema-to-mongoose` since the other libraries didn't quite fit my needs.

Also, I like to generate the `json-schema` from `TypeScript` using `Typson`. It makes it so the `json-schema` is more statically typed.

**Update**

It appears the `Typson` project is dead. Here's another ([typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema)) project which does the same thing, although I've never used it.

Answer (score 2):

Chiming in here since I've also run into this problem and found a solution that is alternative to the suggestions provided.

One can use https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema to take a plain JS object and convert it to both JSON Schema and a Mongoose Schema. I find this tool to be easier in the case of retrofitting existing code with validation and persistence since you will likely already have an example object to start with.